# Easiest way to install Windows Server as a virtual machine on Windows 7 desktop?

Tags: windows, installation, virtualization

I need to test a few of my programs on a Windows Server and was wondering what would be the easiest way to install and run it in a virtual machine.  Should I install VirtualBox and install a Windows Server trial on it?  Something else?

The host is a Windows 7 Home Premium.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

VMware Server is available as a free download and will work nicely.  VirtualBox will work as well.

Comment: So simply installing a virtual server and then installing the Windows Server trial ontop of that would work?

Comment: Technically at that point you are installing Windows Server within the virtual server, but yes that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to install Virtual Box from http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 1):

I'd install [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) on my host, then create the virtual machines I need and install Windows Server on those. VMware server is a dead product. And I've never used any of the FOSS virtualization platforms. Personal preference. From what I've read VirtualBox has come a long way. I just don't believe that it matches up to the capabilities of vmware player/workstation yet.

You don't mention what's involved with your testing. Does the Windows Server VM need to be always online, or only booted when you're working with it?

Comment: I have to say, I think VMware Player is the best solution. I use it extensively.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare and Virtual box both will work nicely. But personally I feel VMWare more easy to use and more user friendly then Virtual Box.

You should intall VMWare Player and install Virtual Windows.